# Time difference in shell (hour)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to calculate time difference stored inside of two variables inside of a **shell script**, I'm observing the following pattern:
hhmm -> 0950

so:

```
time1=1333
time2=0950
```

Now I need to calculate the difference in time between time1 and time2, as for now I have tried:

```
deltaTime=$(($time1-$time2))
```

but I'm facing the following error message

```
1333-0950: value too great for base (error token is "0950")
```

I'm expecting as a result: `$deltaTime=0343`

Unfortunately, I am strictly bound to use this time pattern. I have already researched for a solution online, some of them propose to use date -d... but I couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: What is the expected output if time1 < time2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach has two issues.

First issue: bash recognizes numbers with leading zeroes as octal. You can force base10 by adding `10#` prefix.

Second issue: it is incorrect to consider strings in `hhmm` format as numbers and substract them. e.g. `1333-950=383` but difference between 09:50 and 13:33 is 3 hours and 43 minutes. You should convert string values to common units, e.g. to minutes, substract them and convert back to `hhmm` format.

```
time1=1333
time2=0950

str2min()
{
    printf "%u" $((10#${1%??} * 60 + 10#${1#??}))
}

min2str()
{
    printf "%02u%02u" $(($1 / 60)) $(($1 % 60))
}

time1m=$(str2min $time1)
time2m=$(str2min $time2)

timediff=$(($time1m - $time2m))

deltaTime=$(min2str $timediff)
```

Comment: Good answer overall, but maybe add some more quotes to suppress string-splitting and globbing when there isn't an arithmetic context doing that suppression? Sure, your code being called in a context with `IFS=0` is _unlikely_, but it isn't _impossible_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry but i won't. This is just a proof of concept, not a production release. Otherwise i could add check for input data correctness, handling of negative difference, 12/24 hours format support and more, so it will be hard to see the main idea.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, at the end i will proceed by converting $time1 and $time2 with date -d command, so i will be able to compare as well date, and the diff will be easier as it will be possible to do a subtraction between two variables

Answer (score 1):

You could use this implementation maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

diff_hhmm() {
  local -r from=$1
  local -i from_hh=10#${from:0:2}  # skip 0 chars, read 2 chars (`${from:0:2}`) using base 10 (`10#`)
  local -ri from_mm=10#${from:2:2} # skip 2 chars, read 2 chars (`${from:0:2}`) using base 10 (`10#`)

  local -r upto=$2
  local -ri upto_hh=10#${upto:0:2}
  local -ri upto_mm=10#${upto:2:2}

  local -i diff_hh
  local -i diff_mm

  # Compute difference in minutes
  (( diff_mm = from_mm - upto_mm ))

  # If it's negative, we've "breached" into the previous hour, so adjust
  # the `diff_mm` value to be modulo 60 and compensate the `from_hh` var
  # to reflect that we've already subtracted some of the minutes there.
  if (( diff_mm < 0 )); then
    (( diff_mm += 60 ))
    (( from_hh -= 1 ))
  fi

  # Compute difference in hours
  (( diff_hh = from_hh - upto_hh ))

  # Ensure the result is modulo 24, the number of hours in a day.
  if (( diff_hh < 0 )); then
    (( diff_hh += 24 ))
  fi

  # Print the values with 0-padding if necessary.
  printf '%02d%02d\n' "$diff_hh" "$diff_mm"
}
```

```
$ diff_hhmm 1333 0950
0343
$ diff_hhmm 0733 0950
2143
$ diff_hhmm 0733 0930
2203
```

Or an even shorter implementation using a big arithmetic compound command (`(( ... ))` ) and inlining some variables:

```bash
diff_hhmm_terse() {
  local -i diff_hh diff_mm

  ((
    diff_mm = 10#${1:2:2} - 10#${2:2:2},
    diff_hh = 10#${1:0:2} - 10#${2:0:2},
    diff_hh -= diff_mm < 0 ?  1 : 0,
    diff_mm += diff_mm < 0 ? 60 : 0,
    diff_hh += diff_hh < 0 ? 24 : 0
  ))

  printf '%02d%02d\n' "$diff_hh" "$diff_mm"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, accidentally tapped with finger on smartphone and didn't notice. Could you please make small insignificant edit, i'll be able to upvote it back.

Comment: @dimich ah, no worries then, thanks It left me wondering how wrong could I have been and I couldn't even see it :)

Comment: The one thing I do consider wrong with this answer (not to the point of downvoting it, but to the point of declining to upvote it) is that it's a bit short of explanatory prose unless one is willing to dig into comments. A brief summary before diving into code might be for the better.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the possibility to drop the leading zero?

As you can see from my prompt:

```
Prompt> echo $((1333-0950))
-bash: 1333-0950: value too great for base (error token is "0950")
Prompt> echo $((1333-950))
383
```

Other proposal:

```
date '+%s'
```

Let me give you some examples:

```
date '+%s'
1662357975
... (after some time)
date '+%s'
1662458180
```

=>

```
echo $((1662458180-1662357975))
100205 (amount of seconds)
```

=>

```
echo $(((1662458180-1662357975)/3600))
27 (amount of hours)
```

Comment: `Unfortunately, I am strictly bound to use this time pattern.` .... also note that `383 != 0343` ...

Comment: Oops. I missed the part where `1333` means "13h33m" :-) Why don't you work with time values like `date '+%s'`? This gives the amount of seconds, starting from January 1, 1970. The results of that command give simple values you can do basic calculations with (like simply subtracting them).

Comment: @tink: I elaborated my `date '+%s'` proposal.

Answer (score 0):

This `bash` one-liner may be used if time difference is not negative (that is, time1 >= time2):

```
printf '%04d\n' $(( 10#$time1 - 10#$time2 - (10#${time1: -2} < 10#${time2: -2} ? 40 : 0) ))
```